# Unmount component on click in child component button // React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am struggling with successfully removing component on clicking in button. I found similar topics on the internet however, most of them describe how to do it if everything is rendered in the same component. In my case I fire the function to delete in the child component and pass this information to parent so the state can be changed. However I have no idea how to lift up the index of particular component and this is causing a problem - I believe.

There is a code

PARENT COMPONENT

```
export class BroadcastForm extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          numberOfComponents: [],
          textMessage: ''
        }
        this.UnmountComponent = this.UnmountComponent.bind(this)
        this.MountComponent = this.MountComponent.bind(this)
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this)
      }

      MountComponent () {
        const numberOfComponents = this.state.numberOfComponents
        this.setState({
          numberOfComponents: numberOfComponents.concat(
            <BroadcastTextMessageForm key={numberOfComponents.length} selectedFanpage={this.props.selectedFanpage}
              components={this.state.numberOfComponents}
              onTextChange={this.handleTextChange} dismissComponent={this.UnmountComponent} />)
        })
      }

      UnmountComponent (index) {
        this.setState({
          numberOfComponents: this.state.numberOfComponents.filter(function (e, i) {
            return i !== index
          })
        })
      }

      handleTextChange (textMessage) {
        this.setState({textMessage})
      }

      render () {
        console.log(this.state)
        let components = this.state.numberOfComponents
        for (let i = 0; i < components; i++) {
          components.push(<BroadcastTextMessageForm key={i} />)
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <BroadcastPreferencesForm selectedFanpage={this.props.selectedFanpage}
              addComponent={this.MountComponent}
              textMessage={this.state.textMessage} />

            {this.state.numberOfComponents.map(function (component) {
              return component
            })}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default withRouter(createContainer(props => ({
      ...props
    }), BroadcastForm))
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react'
import { createContainer } from 'react-meteor-data'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import { BroadcastFormSceleton } from './BroadcastForm'

import './BroadcastTextMessageForm.scss'

export class BroadcastTextMessageForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.unmountComponent = this.unmountComponent.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange (e) {
    this.props.onTextChange(e.target.value)
  }

  unmountComponent (id) {
    this.props.dismissComponent(id)
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.props, this.state)
    const textMessage = this.props.textMessage
    return (
      <BroadcastFormSceleton>
        <div className='textarea-container p-3'>
          <textarea id='broadcast-message' className='form-control' value={textMessage}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <div className='float-right'>
          <button type='button'
            onClick={this.unmountComponent}
            className='btn btn-danger btn-outline-danger button-danger btn-small mr-3 mt-3'>
            DELETE
          </button>
        </div>
      </BroadcastFormSceleton>

    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(createContainer(props => ({
  ...props
}), BroadcastTextMessageForm))
```

I am having problem with access correct component and delete it by changing state. Any thoughts how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please fix the following issues in your code.

1. [Do not mutate the state of the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). Use `setState` to immutably change the state.
2. [Do not use array index as the key for your component](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). Try to use an id field which is unique for the component.  This will also help with identifying the component that you would need to unmount.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. As mentioned before, you don't want to use array index as the key.

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      // keep your data in state, as a plain object
      textMessages: [
        {
          message: 'hello',
          id: '2342334', 
        },
        {
          message: 'goodbye!',
          id: '1254534',
        },
      ]
    };
    
    this.handleDeleteMessage = this.handleDeleteMessage.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleDeleteMessage(messageId) {
    // filter by Id, not index
    this.setState({
      textMessages: this.state.textMessages.filter(message => message.id !== messageId)
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.textMessages.map(message => (
          // Use id for key. If your data doesn't come with unique ids, generate them.
          <ChildComponent
            key={message.id}
            message={message}
            handleDeleteMessage={this.handleDeleteMessage}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function ChildComponent({message,  handleDeleteMessage}) {

  function handleClick() {
    handleDeleteMessage(message.id)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {message.message}
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```